# UITableView+YouTubeAPI parsing JSON response for statistics

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube-api

I am getting the JSON response from youtube API v3 for https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id
  and receiving JSON response as

```
{
etag = "\"rFqCJSkEICLP3Hq6a4AADI7kf48/2zirKmd0WgUqY0RzlyD4hlACeWM\"";
items =     (
            {
        etag = "\"rFqCJSkEICLP3Hq6a4AADI7kf48/u4TmQ5XfIQQg6y6u4Od2yULCVlc\"";
        id = "HCcrj0EHvn_Y8";
        kind = "youtube#channel";
        statistics =             {
            commentCount = 0;
            subscriberCount = 21694;
            videoCount = 124582;
            viewCount = 0;
        };
    },
            {
        etag = "\"rFqCJSkEICLP3Hq6a4AADI7kf48/2p4_mjrZLfhO6bDvH-RgAykNQr8\"";
        id = UCX2v47KsDKqajrEYFV7GbBg;
        kind = "youtube#channel";
        statistics =             {
            commentCount = 6460;
            subscriberCount = 494656;
            videoCount = 33;
            viewCount = 713607227;
        };
    }
```

}

when I am trying to display the

```
cell.viewsChannel.text=[[_statistics valueForKeyPath:@"statistics.videoCount"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

the value doesn't display on table view.
I tried to format the output as unsigned long ,int but the correct values don't show.
Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add item to valueForKeyPath

```
cell.viewsChannel.text=[[_statistics valueForKeyPath:@"item.statistics.videoCount"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Thanks Yan,your's solution and some debugging removed my error.